# MSYS2 and Embedding Python. No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, c++, cmake, mingw, msys2

I'm trying to use embedded python in my C++ dll library. The library is built and compiled in MSYS2 using GCC compiler, CMake and Ninja. Python 3.10 is also installed on MSYS2 using pacman. Windows 10 env contains `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` in Path (python is also located there). Python doesn't installed on Windows, only on MSYS2.

This is what `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(python_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Python REQUIRED Development)
add_executable(python_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(python_test PRIVATE Python::Python)
```

Simple test code:

```
int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "import numpy as np\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0)
        exit(120);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I got this error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\someUsername\\CLionProjects\\python_test\\cmake-build-debug\\python_test.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\someUsername\\CLionProjects\\python_test\\cmake-build-debug\\python_test.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.path = [
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python310.zip',
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.10',
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\lib-dynload',
    '',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
Current thread 0x00004564 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

But `python` command work both in MSYS2/MinGW console and Windows cmd. When I specify PYTHONHOME to `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` in Windows 10 environment, I have got the same error again in Clion, and now in Windows command line too. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set `PYTHONHOME=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` and more important `PYTHONPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10;C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages;C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\lib-dynload` and it solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

The error message 'Could not find platform independent libraries ' and 'Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>' indicates that CMake is unable to find the Python installation directory. This is likely because you have Python installed in MINGW64, but you are building your C++ DLL library using the MSYS2 toolchain.

To resolve this issue, you can either:

Set the `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables to the Python installation directory in MINGW64. This can be done in your Windows environment variables, or in your CMakeLists.txt file using the set() command.
Build your C++ DLL library using the MINGW64 toolchain. This can be done by specifying the -G "MinGW Makefiles" option to CMake.